# Strange behavior of inherited properties of UML Stereotypes in Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

I created a profile (MyProfile) which I import via UML profiles in my EA project. MyProfile has one Stereotype (MyStereotype).

1. If I apply MyStereotype to a class (MyClass), I cannot see any tags of the Stereotype. I see the tags only after I do "Sync Tagged values and Constrains".

So the first question: Is it possible to "automatically" see the tags of a Stereotype in the class to which Stereotype is applied (right after I do apply or the Stereotype). Or "Sync..." is the only command to "push" the tags to the MyClass?

2. If I change a name of any Attributes of Stereotype AFTER the import, I cannot see the updated name in the MyClass, even if I do "Sync..." command again, after the change of the attribute name. Of course before the "Sync.." I do "Save as a profile" for the appropriate Profile Package.

So the second question is: Is there a way to update the name of an Attribute in the situation OTHER than delete a reference to a package and Import it again (which seems to be inconvenient and error-prone)?

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't apply a profile to a class but a model. You apply a stereotype of a profile to a class. The synch is only needed if you altered your profile and want to get the newly added stereotype properties (aka EA tagged values) applied to existing stereotyped elements.
2. No. Automatic changes are not foreseen. For a good reason: altering a profile means you have a new version. Changes to a profile will give the whole model a (completely) different semantics. It's very touchy to alter a profile. It shall be stable and changes to a profile must go with a migration procedure. Rule of thumb: think first, act later.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, of course I meant a stereotype in 1 (changed the question accordingly. So I drag the MyStereotype onto the MyClass, and do not see any tags of MyStereotype. I see them only after I do Syncing. AND I do not the new version of tags in MyClass after syncing. In order to see the new tags, I have to delete the Profile from the project and add it again.

Comment: You must be doing something wrong. I can apply a stereo and the TVs appear accordingly.  EA Version?

Comment: Removing an old version of the profile from the menu (using the Remove button in the window from Specialize-Manage MDG menu or using the Resources window) and reimporting the new version of the profile makes sure the expected profile with changes is available for the Synch

Comment: @WorkingMatt EA has 2 ways to remove a profile. One via the Resources and the other via the Advanced in the MDG settings. EAUI...

Comment: @qwerty_so that makes it three ways then, but it depends on how you added the MDG. If you use Specialize - Publish-Tech - Import MDG Technology instead of pointing to a path or URL it's a lot quicker to add and remove MDGs. You make a good point if path used.

Comment: @WorkingMatt And thanks for pointing this out :-) I'll update my answer tomorrow (if my memory will not fail me)...